# Convergence and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, cauchy-sequences

Define **X** as the set of all sequences $\{x_n\}_{(n \in \mathbb{N})}$ of real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$.

> **Question:**
> How to show that if $\{x_n\} \in X$, then there
> is a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $$ |x_K| = \sup \{|x_n|: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
> (i.e. $x_K$ is an element of maximal absolute value), using the definition of convergence?

**Comments:**
I am stuck at this problem and don't know how to find the connection between the supremum and convergence.

We define convergence as: The sequence will converge to **x** if for every **ε > 0** we can find an **N ∈ N** that for all **n≥N**, then **d(x_n,x) < ε**

Comment: Can you show that every sequence that converges to a real value must be bounded?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that mean that the bounded sequence will converge to the supremum of the set X which will be |x_K|. That seems reasonable. What confuses me is in the description it says that lim_n→∞ x_n = 0, or am I not fully understanding.

Comment: No. If the sequence converges it does not have to converge to its supremum, nor to its infimum. We only want so show that sup and inf exist and are attained for at least one element of the sequence. Hint: use the fact that $|x_n|>\epsilon$ for at most *finitely many* $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of convergence to zero, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N>0 |n>N \implies |x_n|<\epsilon$. So there are at most $N$ terms where $|x_n|>1$ for a given sequence. A bounded, non-empty subset of the reals has a supremum by the Completeness Axiom. **Suprema Are Unique** because they are both upper bounds. If one is greater than the other, the lesser is a smaller upper bound, so the larger can't be the least upper bound. So two candidate suprema must be equal. Given a non-empty bounded subset of the reals, $A$ and supremum L, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists a\in A :  \ |a-L|<\epsilon$. Otherwise  $a\in A, a\le L-\epsilon$. So $L-\epsilon$ is a smaller upper bound, a contradiction. This is the **Approximation Property**. Consider the set B' composed of  all elements of B less $sup(B)$. If $0\notin B'$, then it has an infinite number of elements by applying the Approximation property with diminishing values of $\epsilon$. It's finite, so $0\in B'$. So $sup(B)\in B$.

So a bounded, non-empty, finite set contains its supremum as its maximum element. To each sequence in the problem, we can associate this maximum element. Similar reasoning applies to infima, so we are guaranteed a maximum absolute value for any of these sequences.

Let integers $m,n>0 :  \{x_n\}_m=\frac{m}{n} $. In other words, this indexes a set of sequences with $m$ having maximum element $m$. All these sequences converge to $0$. While each set has a supremum for it's absolute value, those suprema have no finite supremum.

Answer (score 0):

If every element in the sequence equals $0$, then any element will work as your $x_K$.

If there are any non-zero elements, pick one, and let its absolute value be $\epsilon$. There is some tail of the sequence in which every element has absolute value less than $\epsilon$. The initial segment, preceding that tail, has finitely many elements, so (at least) one of them has maximum absolute value.

Does that give you enough of a push in the right direction?

Comment: Does it mean that since the sequence {x_n} ∈ X, then it converges to 0 (it's stated that lim_n→∞ x_n = 0.). Which means that the set is bounded and hence a least upper bound (supremum exists). Furthermore, is the lim_n→∞ x_n = supX = 0? And then I can use the definition of convergence and show that it converges to x.

Comment: We can't conclude that the supremum equals $0$. Suppose the sequence is $x_n=1/n$. Then its maximal element is the first element $x_1=1$. It's true that the set is bounded, and hence has a supremum. To show that the supremum is actually attained, you need the finite initial segment, which has a maximum since it's finite.